# Is $F(t)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(tx)e^{-x^2t}}{x^{3/2}}dx$ well defined?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have to see if $$F(t)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(tx)e^{-x^2t}}{x^{3/2}}dx$$ is well defined when $t>0$ and when $t<0$.

---

For it, I have to see if $|F(t)|<\infty$. I have done the following

\begin{align}
\lvert F(t) \rvert &= \bigg \lvert \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(tx)e^{-x^2t}}{x^{3/2}}dx \bigg \rvert \\
&\le \int_0^{\infty} \bigg \lvert \frac{\sin(tx)e^{-x^2t}}{x^{3/2}} \bigg \rvert dx \\
&= \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\lvert \sin(tx) \rvert e^{-x^2t}}{x^{3/2}}dx \\
&= \int_0^{1}\frac{\lvert \sin(tx) \rvert e^{-x^2t}}{x^{3/2}}dx + \int_1^{\infty}\frac{\lvert \sin(tx) \rvert e^{-x^2t}}{x^{3/2}}dx \\
&\le \int_0^{1}\frac{te^{-x^2t}}{x^{1/2}}dx + \int_1^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2t}}{x^{3/2}}dx
\end{align}

- When $t>0$: The first integral $$\int_0^{1}\frac{te^{-x^2t}}{x^{1/2}}dx \le t \int_0^{1}\frac{1}{x^{1/2}}dx=2t<\infty$$ (I can say that it is finite, right?). But the second one?
- And when $t<0$, what can we say?

I don't know how to bound them.

Comment: Hint: You need to control the integrand near zero and near infinity separately. Near $0$, it looks like $\sin(tx)/x^{3/2} \approx t/\sqrt{x}$, by using the Taylor approximation of $\sin$. On the other hand, near infinity, you can use your idea $|\sin(tx)| \leq 1$ and so the integrand looks like $e^{-x^2t}/x^{3/2}$. I would recommend that you break it up into the integral from $0$ to $1$ and $1$ to infinity. Your current bound is infinite because $x^{-3/2}$ has a divergent integral near $0$.

Comment: I have done some edits with what you have said, but I still don't know how to finish it.. @ChrisJanjigian

Comment: Ah sorry didn't read the question carefully. The integral is certainly not Lebesgue integrable if $t<0$, since the absolute value of the integrand diverges. You can see that just by looking at what happens on intervals of the form $x \in [\frac{\pi-\epsilon}{2|t|},\frac{\pi+\epsilon}{2|t|}]$, where the $\sin$ is bounded away from $0$. For the $t>0$, case, you can use $e^{- tx^2} \leq 1$ to control the second integral.

Comment: ok, the case $t>0$ it is now clear, thanks! but in the case $t<0$ how can I see that the integrand diverges? @ChrisJanjigian

Comment: Look at the intervals $[\frac{k(\pi-\epsilon)}{2|t|},\frac{k(\pi+\epsilon)}{2|t|}]$, so the sin term is bounded from below in absolute value. As $x$ goes to infinity, the thing multiplying the sin goes to infinity due to the $e^{-x^2 t}$ term.

Comment: As it has been shown that the integral converges, the integral has a closed-form of $I = 2 t^{3/4} \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right) {}_{1} F_{1} \left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{2},-\frac{t}{4}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

As @Chris Janjigian already commented, $\Re(t) > 0$ is required.

Now, using what you  wrote is
$$\lvert F(t) \rvert \leq  \int_0^{1}\frac{te^{-x^2t}}{x^{1/2}}dx + \int_1^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2t}}{x^{3/2}}dx$$
$$I_1=\int_0^{1}\frac{te^{-x^2t}}{x^{1/2}}dx=\frac{1}{2} t^{3/4} \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{4},t\right)\right)$$ For the second one, one integration by parts leads to
$$J=\int\frac{e^{-x^2t}}{x^{3/2}}dx=\frac{2 \left( t^{1/4} \sqrt{x}\, \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4},t x^2\right)-e^{-t
   x^2}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}$$
$$I_2=\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{-x^2t}}{x^{3/2}}dx=2 e^{-t}-2 t^{1/4} \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4},t\right)$$
$$\lvert F(t) \rvert \leq \frac{1}{2} t^{3/4} \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4},t\right)\right)+2 e^{-t}-2 t^{1/4} \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4},t\right)$$